# Material UI Autocomplete using previous state options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to suggest data using the autocomplete component based on 2 queries that fetch data from GraphQL.

```
    const handleSearchChange = (evt, newInputValue) => {
      const {
        agentsEmail,
        prefix,
        appsName,
        role,
        fromDate,
        toDate,
      } = this.props;
      console.log("handle Search Change")
      this.setState({ userInput: evt.target.value });
      if (newInputValue.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ open: true });
        setTimeout(() => {  this.prepareFilterData(appsName, agentsEmail, prefix, role, fromDate, toDate); }, 500);
      } else {
        this.setState({ open: false });
      }
    }

    const handleSelection = (evt, evtSelection, reason) => {
      console.log(reason, "REASON handle Selection")

      this.setState({ selection: evtSelection });

      /* map over selection and for each element push to listings the element.id
      to build the list of ids to be used by the seearch button handle event */
      this.state.selection.map( (selection) => listings.push(selection.id))
      console.log(this.state.selection, "SELECTION")
    }


    <Autocomplete
            id="listings-filter"
            multiple
            open={this.state.open}
            onOpen={handleOpen}
            onClose={() => this.setState({ open: false })}
            options={filterList}
            limitTags={4}
            groupBy={(option) => option.key}
            disableCloseOnSelect
            onChange={handleSelection}
            onInputChange={handleSearchChange}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
            renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
             <React.Fragment>
               <Checkbox
                 icon={icon}
                 checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                 style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                 checked={selected}
               />
             {option.value}
             </React.Fragment>
            )}
            renderInput={(params) => (
             <TextField {...params} label="Search listings by" placeholder="Address, MLS" />
            )}
          />
```

I'm using a class component, and the options are a list I formatted to allow them to be grouped with the Autocomplete component, but it is always using a previous state of the options. for example:
I type **ca** on the input and it fetches 100 values, but it uses that 100 values when I blur the input which clears the input and it loads the 100 fields. then when I type something else the empty options got loaded. I always need to do +1 change event to got the actual options list, I tried setting to false the **clearOnBlur** property which didn't solve the issue because since the change event is not fired when blurring the input it never update the state (+1).
Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks in advice
Here a animated example of my issue:
[image]

EDIT: This behavior also happen when deleting the selected options or selecting them, if I select one of the options the change event reflects an empty list, when I select a second one it reflect just the first I selected.

This is the function I use to format and update the **filterList** I fetch the data with the fetchMls and fetchAddresses then using the **mergeFilterData** I update the filter list used on the options property

```
  prepareFilterData = async (appsName, agentsEmail, prefix, role, fromDate, toDate) => {
    await this.fetchMls(appsName, agentsEmail, prefix, role, fromDate, toDate);
    await this.fetchAddresses(appsName, agentsEmail, prefix, role, fromDate, toDate);
    this.setState({
      filterList: mergeFilterData(this.state.fetchedAddresses, this.state.fetchedMls, [])
    });
    console.log(this.state.filterList, "FINAL DATA")
    /* this.setState({
      filteredList: handleListChange(userInput, listingsList, 0.5),
    }); */
  }
```

EDIT2: Here is one of the functions I use to fetch the data, when the data is fetched is formated and saved on a state to be used.

```
  fetchMls = async (appsName, agentsEmail, prefix, role, fromDate, toDate) => {
    const enumerationAppName = appsName.map((appName) => appName.enumeration);
    const listAgents = agentsEmail.map((agent) => agent.name || agent);
    console.log(this.state.userInput, "USER INPUT ON FETCH MLS")
    const query = {
      query: GET_LISTINGS_BY_MLS_PREFIX_QUERY,
      variables: {
        appsName: enumerationAppName,
        agentsEmail: listAgents,
        prefix,
        fromDate: formatDate(fromDate),
        toDate: formatDate(toDate),
        mlsPrefix: this.state.userInput || "1",
      },
    };

    applicationClient
      .query(query)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          if (!isEmpty(response.data.getListingsByMlsPrefix.data)) {
            const result = response.data.getListingsByMlsPrefix.data.map(
              (listing) => listing
            );
            const formatedMls = formatMls(result);
            this.setState({ fetchedMls: formatedMls });
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({ fetchedMls: [] });
      });
  };
```

Comment: Hi, how are you implementing prepareFilterData?

Comment: Hi, are you referring to the filterOptions?

Comment: yes, where are you updating the filterList value?

Comment: I set the filterList after fetching and formatting the data, I updated the question showing the function that has this responsability

Comment: I assume that in fetchMls and fetchAddresses you are updating the state when data is ready, so it is possible that this.setState({filterList..}) is running before those state updates. For example, if you want to log filterList, the best way to do it is on setState callback this.setState({
      filterList: mergeFilterData(this.state.fetchedAddresses, this.state.fetchedMls, [])
    }, ()=> console.log(this.state.filterList, "FINAL DATA"));

Comment: actually fetchMls and fetchAddresses update other list states which I merge on the mergeFilterData and that merged list is the list I use to update the filterList(autocomplete options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't related to material UI component, the problem was related with the data I was fetching, as I was fetching 3 different queries I was having a race condition error, so I solved it by resolving all the promises using Promises.all() if is useful for anyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process data after state updates, the best way is on callback function:

```
 const handleSearchChange = (evt, newInputValue) => {
      const {
        agentsEmail,
        prefix,
        appsName,
        role,
        fromDate,
        toDate,
      } = this.props;
      console.log("handle Search Change")
      this.setState({ 
        userInput: newInputValue,
        open: newInputValue > 0
      });
      if (newInputValue.length > 0) {
         setTimeout(() => {  this.prepareFilterData(appsName, agentsEmail,   prefix, role, fromDate, toDate); }, 500);
      }
      
    }

const handleSelection = (evt, evtSelection, reason) => {
  console.log(reason, "REASON handle Selection")
  this.setState({ selection: evtSelection }, ()=> {
      this.state.selection.map( (selection) => listings.push(selection.id))
      console.log(this.state.selection, "SELECTION")
  });

  /* map over selection and for each element push to listings the element.id
  to build the list of ids to be used by the seearch button handle event */

}
```

I don't know what is in this.fetchMls and this.fetchAddresses functions, but  I recommend you to get the data directly, something like this:

```
 prepareFilterData = async (appsName, agentsEmail, prefix, role, fromDate, toDate) => {
        const fetchedAddresses = await this.fetchMls(appsName, agentsEmail, prefix, role, fromDate, toDate);
        const fetchedMls = await this.fetchAddresses(appsName, agentsEmail, prefix, role, fromDate, toDate);
        this.setState({
          filterList: mergeFilterData(fetchedAddresses, fetchedMls, [])
        }, ()=> console.log(this.state.filterList, "FINAL DATA"));
       
      }
```

I hope this help you ;)

Comment: thanks for you answer, I tried that, but I'm having the same issue, it is really strange that the component always uses the previous state for the options